# Way to quickly send something to outlook

Tags: outlook

Many things that I need to do I receive via outlook. However, sometimes I just hear something or think of something, and would like to send this to outlook *with minimal distraction*. I don't care whether it arrives as an email, or directly on the todo list.

On the Iphone I had a flow like this:

#### Iphone: Send mail to self:

1. Open app (for example:To Myself)
2. Type message
3. Click send

On the windows phone, the best flows I have found so far:

#### Windows phone Option 1: Create task

1. Open calender
2. Click three dots in bottom right corner
3. Click tasks
4. Click plus
5. Type message
6. Click save

#### Windows phone Option 2: Send a mail

1. Open email
2. Click plus
3. Type few characters
4. Click on my mail
5. Type message
6. Click send

I have a feeling that one way to improve on these flows is by creating shortcuts on the computer and placing them on the phone, but have not succesfully figured this out.

Note that I am not interested in ways that solve this outside outlook as I also need to use the notes easily from any device that lets me access outlook.

---

The question:

## What is the most efficient way to send something from the windows phone to outlook

If a free solution is available that would be preferred, but I am willing to pay a small fee for the right app.

Comment: If you have Cortana enabled, "Take a note" or "Remind me" or similar voice commands are useful shortcuts for the first few steps of your first option above. Also, it would be entirely possible to write an app that lets you simply send emails to yourself, but I don't know if anybody has done so.

Comment: I have an app written that I think would do what you want, with one exception: due to Windows Phone limitations, you are forced to physically hit the Send button in the email client. I can auto-create the message, but you must hit Send. For this reason, I'm not sure it will be that much faster. However, if you still want the app, I can publish it.

Comment: @Shawn If the app can approach the functionality as described in the iPhone example, I think it would be a nice solution.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin  It works as described, except I found one more limitation (I had originally developed it for Windows 10, then copied to WP). In WP, I can't automatically close the app, since the email sharing dialog is part of the app. I can publish it when I get home tonight.